# PHP mysql_fetch_array Issue

Tags: php, mysql

I can't seem to get past this error.

**Warning**:  mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in **/windsor.php** on line **47**

```
if ($insertdb == NULL)
  mysql_query("INSERT INTO `asd` (`id`, `1`, `2`,`3`, `4`, `5`, `pubdate`) VALUES (296, maddeal', 'Windsor', 'ON', '', '', '') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `1`=VALUES(`1`),`2`=VALUES(`2`),`3`=VALUES(`3`),`4`=VALUES(`4`),`5`=VALUES(`5`)") or die(mysql_error());
 else
//Check and see if value has changed...

$checksql = mysql_query("SELECT `1` FROM deal WHERE `id`= 296") or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($checksql))
  {
  $checksqlver = $row['deal'];
  }

$checksqlver = mysql_real_escape_string($checksqlver);
//$checksqlver = stripslashes($checksqlver);
echo "$checksqlver<br>";

if ($checksqlver == $insertdb)
  exit();
 else
  echo "No Match<br>";

//percent
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you connect to the database using `mysql_connect`?

That would cause the error you are describing.

Comment: Yes, I have that specified at the top, just didn't post.  Other scripts work, just this one is giving me grief...

Comment: You also have an `else` statement there where you don't have any code until the `$checksql = ...` try removing that `else`.

Comment: replaced
else
//Check and see if value has changed...
with
else
    echo "Moving On";

Not that best fix, but it works.

Comment: Excellent. PHP could really stand to make their errors a little more specific as to what the problem actually is... In your case it is because you passed a null value to `mysql_fetch_array` because `$checksql` was declared in a different scope.

Answer (score 0):

In your select query should 1 have apostrophes around it?